# haproxy starts two processes, normal or not?

Tags: python, haproxy, suse

background:I wrote a python script to read database, update haproxy.cfg and reload haproxy per minute. To avoid missing request, I referred to [HAProxy: Reloading Your Config With Minimal Service Impact](http://www.mgoff.in/2010/04/18/haproxy-reloading-your-config-with-minimal-service-impact/#wrapper) and linux command "man haproxy".  Now, I reached the goal, and no bug appears yet.  What confused me is that two haproxy processes, sometimes three working at the same time. In other words, option '-sf' doesn't work always.  Is it normal or not, and why?

part of the python script is:

```
if 0 != os.system('/usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f /usr/local/sbin/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)'):
        print '[ERROR] restart haproxy fails'
```

the 'haproxy.cfg' file is like such:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local3 info
        maxconn 5000
        daemon
        nbproc 1

defaults
        log             global
        mode            tcp
        option          dontlognull
        retries         3
        maxconn         2000
        timeout connect    5000
        timeout client     50000
        timeout server     50000

listen  xtbroker_1_20001_7080 0.0.0.0:58002
        mode    tcp
        balance roundrobin
        server xtbroker_1_20001_7080_0 127.0.0.1:58101 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2
        server xtbroker_1_20001_7080_1 127.0.0.1:58102 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2

listen  xtbroker_1_21001_8090 0.0.0.0:58004
        mode    tcp
        balance roundrobin
        server xtbroker_1_21001_8090_0 127.0.0.1:58103 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2

listen  xtbroker_1_21001_8888 0.0.0.0:58006
        mode    tcp
        balance roundrobin
        server xtbroker_1_21001_8888_0 127.0.0.1:58104 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2

listen  xtbroker_1_21001_1001 0.0.0.0:58008
        mode    tcp
        balance roundrobin
        server xtbroker_1_21001_1001_0 127.0.0.1:58105 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2
        server xtbroker_1_21001_1001_1 127.0.0.1:58106 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2
        server xtbroker_1_21001_1001_2 127.0.0.1:58107 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2
        server xtbroker_1_21001_1001_3 127.0.0.1:58108 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2
        server xtbroker_1_21001_1001_4 127.0.0.1:58109 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2


listen  xtbroker_1_21001_3010 0.0.0.0:58012
        mode    tcp
        balance roundrobin
        server xtbroker_1_21001_3010_0 127.0.0.1:58112 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2


listen  xtbroker_1_21001_8060 0.0.0.0:58018
        mode    tcp
        balance roundrobin
        server xtbroker_1_21001_8060_0 127.0.0.1:58117 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2
        server xtbroker_1_21001_8060_1 127.0.0.1:58118 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 2
```

```
root@linux-kas9:/home/rzrk/server/pyScripts # ps aux | grep haproxy
root     12258  0.0  0.0   6016  1552 ?        Ss   14:19   0:00 /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f /usr/local/sbin/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf 19512
root     17500  0.0  0.0   5936  1152 ?        Ss   14:56   0:00 /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f /usr/local/sbin/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf 11722
root     21187  0.0  0.0   5920   800 pts/4    S+   14:56   0:00 grep haproxy
root     47545  0.0  0.0   5900  1524 ?        Ss   14:38   0:00 /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f /usr/local/sbin/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf 42333
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
```

Comment: When gracefully reloading haproxy using `-sf`, it will always start a new process. The old processes will continue to serve the already existing connections while new connections are served by the new haproxy process. Once they are all closed, the old process will go away. This is the intended behavior.

Comment: Apart from that, your question is unfortunately off-topic on Stack Overflow as it does not concern programming but is related to the configuration of a loadbalancer. This might be more on-topic on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: if so, '-sf' is safer than '-st'.  Additionally, didn't know serverfault.com before

Comment: With `-sf`, old connections will continue to be served until they close. With `-st` existing connections will be forcefully closed and the process will vanish almost instantly. Most often, `-sf` is what you want as this ensures that the reload is almost unnoticeable for your users.